# background images not found in GAE

Tags: jquery, css, image, google-app-engine

I have a bad problem when loading most of background pictures in my GAE front-end app.

**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".**

My app is a simple website, with no GAE backend.
I am using Eclipse with Google AppEngine Plugin.

The background pictures are changed every 10 seconds using JQuery.

*What I dont understand is that out of my 16 background pictures, the 3rd and 11th are always found, 
whereas the rest are never.* (And no, the name is not wrong I have checked that million of times..)

*If there is some systematic error in the way I access the pictures, then shouldnt they all fail?*

Now obviously I am missing something here but what? I have tried to google for answer but I dont get it, everything works fine locally.

Any other small pictures I have for icons and header always load perfectly. The problem is with the big background images. There is no difference between browsers.

Things I tried (with no success):

- I increased the stack size (-Xmx10m -Xss10m) to try to see if the deployment somehow failed.
- I do not have any app.yaml file, I tried to add a simple app.yaml file and telling the engine that my images are in "images" folder.
- i moved my background pictures from "images/background" into "images"
- Made a test in which I changed all the pictures really simple with just a single color background, and then all pictures were OK.. And later again all the pictures failed except the 3rd and 11th with no code changes.

Please, any idea what I am missing here? If things work locally, but not in GAE, is there a list somewhere what is the difference in terms of environment..?

Some of the code is below:

```
var photos = [ {
"image" : "p1.jpg",}, {
"image" : "p2.jpg",}, {
"image" : "p3.jpg",}, { 
// pictures 4-10
    "image" : "p11.jpg",}, { 
// pictures 12-15
    "image" : "p16.jpg",
        }
        ];


// Set the background image of the new active container
$("#backgroundimg" + activeContainer).css({
    "background-image" : "url(images/" + photoObject.image + ")",
    "display" : "block",
    "z-index" : currentZindex
});

// Fade out the current container
// and display the header text when animation is complete
$("#backgroundimg" + currentContainer).fadeOut(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        animating = false;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: how are you serving those images? and did you actually try to hit that url (your-website-url/images/p16.jpg, for example)?

Comment: Without a properly configured app.yaml the images won't get uploaded when you deploy the static files.

Answer (score 0):

please try referencing your images absolutely, meaning from the document root rather than relatively.  relative reference, from the current directory:

```
url(images/" + photoObject.image + ")"
```

absolute reference, works regardless of current directory (which i'm wondering if somehow google app engine is altering dynamically given some other bit of code.

```
url(/images/" + photoObject.image + ")"
```

i'm also curious about the photos object.  given the small amount of context, this might be easier to work with:

```
var photos = ["p1.jpg", "p2.jpg", "p3.jpg", "p11.jpg", "p16.jpg"];
```

good luck!

`